# ActionMailer Views with Rails 5 api_only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently trying to set up a mailer with my Rails api server. Currently, I get the following error: `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_mailer/welcome_email with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "user_mailer"
):`

There is currently a view at `views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb`

My `users_mailer.rb` looks as follows:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'xx@xxx.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/login'
    mail(to: 'xxx@xxxxx.com', subject: 'Welcome to the site')
  end
end
```

My controller calls the mailer like such:

```
def show
   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
   render json: @user
end
```

I've tried setting `config.api_only = false` without any luck.

Comment: Someone also faced the same issue like you https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/issues/23 .. :)

Comment: I've restarted the app several times, and I've also stopped spring several times.

Comment: I am not seeing any obvious. You may add an issue there in the repo.

Comment: Thanks for looking over the code for me. I've posted a new issue in the Rails repo.

Comment: can you give the issue link here in the post itself. So that future reader can also get help. thanks

Comment: Of course. Here it is: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23526

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23526#issuecomment-180885923):

> Ok - found the error. You have the views stored in views/user_mailer/*, instead of app/views/user_mailer/*. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep:

```
views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb
```

Instead of:

```
app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb
```